# Reference fields from DE not tied to Journey in Email Template

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a need to pull current Mortgage Rates in to an email template in Marketing Cloud. There is daily transmission of the rates to a Data Extension via external API. Will need to display these in various email templates that will be used in Journeys with DE entry source. The Data Extension that is being ingested with the rates via API would be separate from the Journey DEs.

Is there a way (via Ampscript I am guessing) to lookup the values in Mortgage Rates DE and display in Email Template?

Comment: You should watch the LookUp functions here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible as has already been mentioned with a shared value to look up on, but if the information is just 'content' not related to a particular individual that just needs to be a snippet in various templates, this is also possible. If the latter, I'd approach it in the following way.

Here's an example (I've put in a UK mortgage provider for this):

```
%%[
SET @MORTGAGE_RATES_CONTENT="MORTGAGE_RATES_CONTENT"
SET @HALIFAX="HALIFAX"
SET @Rows = LookupRows("MORTGAGE_RATES_DE","CATEGORY",@MORTGAGE_RATES_CONTENT,"PROVIDER", @HALIFAX)
IF RowCount(@Rows) > 0 THEN
SET @HALIFAX_MORTGAGE_RATE = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"MORTGAGE_RATE")
SET @HALIFAX_RATE_EXPIRY = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"RATE_EXPIRY")
SET @HALIFAX_DESCRIPTION = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"DESCRIPTION")
SET @HALIFAX_IMAGE_URL = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1),"IMAGE_URL")
ENDIF
]%%
```

If you have a non-sendable data extension with two primary key fields (CATEGORY and PROVIDER in this case) then you can duplicate this block of AMPscript to reference each data extension row (the block above is isolating the row based on the provider value but you can use whatever works for your use case). You can of course add more variables to output depending on the data extension fields you have.

Then you can simply print the values in your email:

```
%%=V(@HALIFAX_MORTGAGE_RATE)=%%
```

This is very much for 'set and forget' - if you need to make regular changes then there are better solutions out there.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

There should be a field matching in both the DEs for lookup function. I'm assuming "SubscriberKey" to be that field

```
%%[    
set @rates = Lookup('MortgageRatesDE','Rates','SubscriberKey',_SubscriberKey)
]%%
%%=v(@rates)=%%
```

- **MortagageRatesDE** - Your DE name
- **Rates** - DE Field from which
  to return a value
- **SubscriberKey** - DE Field used to identify row containing lookup
  value
- **_SubscriberKey** - Personalization string to match the string